# combine dictionary with numpy using key

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary, merge

Suppose that I have a dict like this

```
raw = {'y': [2, 3, 5, 7, 8], 'x': [440, 438, 435, 430, 420]}
```

and a numpy array of 10 entries

```
ddm = np.zeros(10, dtype=np.int)
# [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
```

I'd like to merge them from y as key and x as value, like this:

```
[  0   0 440 438   0 435   0 430 420   0]
```

I could iterate through the keys, but is there an efficient way to merge them such that I have?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Numpy supports multiple indices

```
index = raw['y']
values = raw['x']
ddm[index] = values
```

or directly

```
ddm[raw['y']] = raw['x']
```

Comment: haha, this is a simple solution, I didn't know. I've tried np.combine/merge and a lot other things... great, thank you!

Comment: Thanks. Lookup numpy indexing, it is very interesting. Also, please accept answer if it worked